# 'fromEvent' always observing, but 'from(myArray)' terminates observing after all values are processed

Tags: rxjs, observable

So Im struggling a bit with my understanding of RxJs and observables.

Can it be explained why 'fromEvent' always reacts to a new event no matter how much time has passed without a new value...yet pushing new values into an existing array that is being observed using 'from' doesn't work in the same way if they are both observables at this point and should react to async events why do we need to use 'Subject' for arrays?

I have seen we need to use a 'Subject' for an array ...but why? I would like to understand the reason/mechanism

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little bit like asking why and `Array.forEach` doesn't also iterate over items I add to an array via `.push` while `addEventListener()` continues listening for events even far in the future.

The behaviors of the two are different because the underlying data structures are different.

**#fromArray**

For an `Array` the implementation is essentially:

```
function fromArray(array) {
  return new Observable(observer => {
    try {
      // Iterate through each item in the array and emit it to the Observer
      array.forEach(item => observer.next(item));
      // Array iteration is synchronous, which when we get here we are done iterating
      observer.complete();
    } catch (e) { observer.error(e) }
  })
}
```

Where the function passed to the observable gets run each time a subscriber subscribes to the `Observable`. Because `Arrays` don't have a mechanism to detect changes to them there is no way to listen for additional updates to a native array (note: I am ignoring monkey-patching or creating some sort of substitute array data type that *does* support such things for simplicity).

**#fromEvent**

The `fromEvent` on the other hand would look more like:

```
function fromEvent(node, eventName, selector) {
  // Convert the passed in event or just use the identity
  let transform = selector || x => x;

  // Construct an Observable using the constructor 
  return new Observable(observer => {
    // Build a compatible handler, we also use this for the unsubscribe logic
    const nextHandler = (value) => {
      try {
        observer.next(transform(value));
      } catch (e) { observer.error(e); }
    }
    // Start listening for events
    node.addEventListener(eventName, nextHandler);

    // Return a way to tear down the subscription when we are done
    return () => node.removeEventListener(eventName, nextHandler);
  })
  // Shares the underlying Subscription across multiple subscribers
  // so we don't create new event handlers for each.
  .share();
}
```

Here we are simply wrapping the native event handler (obviously the real implementation is more robust than this). But because the underlying source is actually an event handler which *does* have a mechanism to report new event (by definition really), we continue to get events in perpetuity (or until we unsubscribe).

Comment: Hey pauldniels, thanks for taking time to answer... regards "The behaviors of the two are different because the underlying data structures are different." - I thought that the point of RxJS is to be data structure agnostic...and this is the reason why you can treat an array, event, http call all as observable streams without the need for specific business logic to deal with the type of data structure. I guess I incorrectly assumed that creating an observable from data static/dynamic it would follow the observer pattern and notify the subscribers on any change...I assumed this was RxJS purpose?

Comment: Btw, I just realised you are paulpdaniels of 'RxJS in Action', I bought the book a few days ago in a desperate bid to try and quickly wrap my head around RxJS :)

Comment: @user1806692 understandable assumption, and believe me you aren't the only one to have it. re: unified business logic, its not so much about making each data source behave the same way, just about having a unified way of acting across them. i.e. a pipeline built for an `ArrayObservable` can do all the same things as a `FromEventObservable`. Observers aren't supposed to care about *when* events emit only *what* they emit.

Comment: It might be easier to think of the two factory methods as attacking different use cases. `fromArray` is for pre-canned data, whereas `fromEvent` is for traditional event handlers. If we had an `Array` that *could* emit on event change (similar to how Vue patches `Arrays`), then we could easily create an Observable for it, but since the emission mechanism would likely be an event handler we would still use `fromEvent` under the covers. Does that make sense?

Comment: Also, hope you enjoy the book!